# HTML5/Javascript + Web Services

Tags: html, design-patterns

If developing web applications using **ASP.NET MVC** or **Ruby on Rails** make the application use the **MVC design pattern**, then if I build my application using only **HTML5/Javascript + backend webservices** (like WCF rest), then which design pattern will my application follow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you structure you application ;)

If you use popular "thick client JS" frameworks like [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) you end up using a MVC style as well. Only change is that the model access it's data through the webservice. Most framework abstracts away this as well, so you can switch to localStorage, WebSocket or something else.

From my personal experience using Backbone.js, I really like the MVC pattern for client applications. It really helps structuring large js apps.

**Edit:**

Knockout.js is actually MVVM, from the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html):

> Developers familiar with Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET MVC, or other MV*
>   technologies may see MVVM as a real-time form of MVC with declarative
>   syntax. In another sense, you can think of KO as a general way to make
>   UIs for editing JSON data… whatever works for you :)

Comment: So if I am not using any of these frameworks (knockout, Backbone, other...), then my application is not following any patterns right?

Comment: That completely depends on how you have decided to structure it. MVC is not dictated by what framework you use, it's merely a way of describing the architecture and responsibility of the different parts of you app. Since a lot of large JS applications follow the trainwreck-pattern they are very hard to maintain. MVC is a well-adopted pattern that you should consider adopting if your application is hard to reason about. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller